# Deleting bitbucket repositories

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I want to delete my atlassian account, workspace, project and all my bitbucket repos but I am bit confused by the docs.

```
What’s not deleted

To preserve Git authorship and other records, we won't automatically delete the following:

- Any workspaces (and repositories or snippets owned by these workspaces) for which you are the last remaining admin.

- Snippets you created which are owned by a workspace.

- Comments you've made in repositories you don't own, but the reference to your Bitbucket Cloud username is changed to ‘Former user’.

- Commits you've made in repositories you don't own, but there is no longer a link to your user profile; although, your email address is retained within these commits (due to the nature of Git and Mercurial).

- Issues and issue comments you've made in issue trackers you don't own, but the reference to your Bitbucket Cloud username is changed to ‘Former user’.
```

What does it mean by

`Any workspaces (and repositories or snippets owned by these workspaces) for which you are the last remaining admin.`

If I delete a repository in the workspace **before** deleting the atlassian account does this guarantee the repository is completely removed from the cloud? (e.g. all files and there history, commits, branches etc)

I also cant seem to delete the workspace... there is no delete button in the settings.

For reference
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/delete-an-account/

Comment: This is a programming site. How does this involve programming?

Comment: Sorry which meta should this be in

Comment: "Workspaces" are a bitbucket/Atlassian concept, not related to Git. I'm no Atlassian expert so I can't go any further than that, but you'll want to ask the Atlassian folks.

Answer (score 0):

> does this guarantee the repository is completely removed from the cloud?

There's an important difference between making a repository inaccessible to anyone and removing the data entirely from Atlassian's servers and backups.

If your goal is to just take down visible repository content (the former), you can do that without deleting your account by simply changing all the repository settings to private and removing all users from the repository. If you are looking for the latter "stronger" deletion (for example if your repository contains sensitive information that should not be accessible to Atlassian employees), then you'll probably need a support ticket to pursue that.

If you just want content hidden from the world and are set on deleting the account, I would opt for paranoia and make each repo private and delete each repo individually (and each snippet if those have content) before deleting the account. The empty workspace may remain, but with no repos or snippets, there won't be anything for the world to see.